# sessionFactory - Spring hibernate integration problem

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jpa

I'm new in Spring Framework (2.5.6) and I have Hibernate integration problem on Glassfish server (open source edition 3). I will add that when I use Tomcat server (v 7.0) everything is OK.

I have the following code (`springwebglassfishhibernate-data.xml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="carRentalPersistenceUnit" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean"
    factory-bean="entityManagerFactory" factory-method="getSessionFactory">
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

But when I run server i get following error:

```
SEVERE: Exception while loading the app
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/configuration_xmls/springwebglassfishhibernate-data.xml]: No matching factory method found: factory bean 'entityManagerFactory'; factory method 'getSessionFactory'
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:117)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:126)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:241)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:236)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:339)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:183)
at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:272)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:305)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:320)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1176)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$900(CommandRunnerImpl.java:83)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1235)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1224)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:365)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:204)
at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:166)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:100)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:245)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Maybe, I will paste part of my pom.xml file showing dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.146</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-hibernate2</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>oro</groupId>
        <artifactId>oro</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
        <artifactId>fop</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xalan</groupId>
        <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-struts</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.portlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>portlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-compat</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-servlet-wildcard</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-el</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2-b19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>ejb3-persistence</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2.Beta1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-script-ant</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

What is the best solution for this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer not getting the hibernate session factory into this. JPA defines the so called vendor adapters, so you can use it instead. Here's a snippet from my current working configuration:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="puName" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean 
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="${hibernate.showSql}" />
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="${hibernate.dialect}" />
            <property name="generateDdl" value="${hibernate.generateDDL}" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

(the `${..}` properties are resolved by a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`. You can also put them directly there)

Then of course you should use a JPA transaction manager:

```
<bean id="jpaTransactionManager"
     class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
```

And use `@PersistenceContext private EntityManager entityManager;` rather than the hibernate session.

Answer (score 1):

Change it to

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean"
    factory-bean="entityManagerFactory" factory-method="getSessionFactory">
</bean>
```

---

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean"
          p:dataSource-ref="dataSource">
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.mycompany.app.model.Book</value>
            </list>
        </property>

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <value>

                hibernate.dialect org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
                REST OF THE PROPS               
            </value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

and configure data source properly